# how to set permissions of files downloaded to common local maven repository

Tags: maven

I wish to set up a common local maven repository on a build server which all users with accounts on that server in the `dev` group would be able to access when running builds with maven.

This is easily enough done you just add a <localRepository> tag.  But the problem is that permissions on the files that get downloaded from central to the local repository are `-rw-r-----` whereas I want `-rw-rw----`.

Is there a maven setting that does this or is a system setting required?

Update: Excuse me for living.
OF COURSE I looked at the official Maven sites.  There are no documents that talk to my use case. I looked [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-settings/settings.html) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html).  There are <filePermissions> and <directoryPermissions> elements for the <server> element, but they do not cover the permissions on files downloaded FROM the server.

Update 2:  This is not a "build machine" in the sense of Continuous Integration or anything like that.  It is a place where developers can do "local-ish" test builds from which easy access to development servers is also possible, something that is not available from their local machines.  The purpose here is saving disk space.  And this use case is **specifically mentioned** in [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) which says:

> localRepository: This value is the path of this build system’s local
>   repository. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository. This
>   element is especially useful for a main build server allowing all
>   logged-in users to build from a common local repository.

But the question of download file permissions is nowhere mentioned.

Comment: Why should users have access to a repository which is on the build server? Use a repository manager which offers such thing for the whole company...

Comment: I guess I wasn't being clear.  This is a local build server for a small organization in a megacorporation. By "build server"  I meant a server to which several developers have access for the purpose of doing local test builds, and which has access to other development servers.  It is not a CI-type build server.  We have a corporate nexus but see no need to repeat copies of all the usual jars for what are essentially local builds.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd {MAVEN_HOME}
find repository -type d | xargs chmod g+s
```

Every file or directory created under the repository will belong to the group.

Now, create file /etc/mavenrc with this content or add to it if it doesn't exist

```
umask 0007
```

The mvn executable "source"'s this file ( ./etc/mavenrc ) so that the umask is in effect while maven runs but only for the duration of the maven process, after which umask reverts to its default value.  This umask prevents other users from even seeing the file but does allow members of the group all permissions (including write permission, which is what we are after).

Thus all files that maven writes to this repository are group writable.

If you'd rather the files be readable by non-group users, then
`umask 0003` in /etc/mavenrc will do the trick.